# How does Passport Google Strategy communicate with a database?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I followed a tutorial that uses Google Strategy to check if the user has been added to the database before. That process is done in the passport.use( new GoogleStrategy (....) function. It stores the user correctly but I'm still confused about how it communicates with dynamo DB in that function.

app.js

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");
var passport = require("passport");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var passport = require("passport");
var session = require("express-session");
var DynamoDBStore = require("connect-dynamodb")(session);
var GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth2").Strategy;
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config({ path: __dirname + "/.env" });
var GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
var GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET;

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback",
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    function (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      // asynchronous verification, for effect...
      process.nextTick(function () {
        User.findOne({ "google.id": profile.id }, function (err, user) {
          if (err) return done(err);

          if (user) {
            // if a user is found, log them in
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            // if the user isnt in our database, create a new user
            var newUser = new User();

            // set all of the relevant information
            newUser.google.id = profile.id;
            newUser.google.token = token;
            newUser.google.name = profile.displayName;
            newUser.google.email = profile.emails[0].value; // pull the first email

            // save the user
            newUser.save(function (err) {
              if (err) throw err;
              return done(null, newUser);
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  )
);
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});

var app = express();
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_SECRET,
  region: "us-west-1",
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);

var users = require("./routes/users");
var drinksRouter = require("./routes/drinks");
var ingredientsRouter = require("./routes/ingredients");
var liquorRouter = require("./routes/liquors");
var justIngredients = require("./routes/justIngredients");

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3001");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(logger("dev"));

/*
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send({ title: "Drinks API Entry Point" });
});
*/

var options = {
  table: "app-sessions",
  AWSConfigJSON: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_SECRET,
    region: "us-west-1",
  },
  client: dynamodb,
};
//initialzie session
app.use(
  session({
    store: new DynamoDBStore(options),
    secret: "new user",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//   serialized and deserialized.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  next();
});
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send({ user: req.user });
});

app.get("/account", ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send({ user: req.user });
});

app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send({ user: req.user });
});
app.get("/users", function (req, res) {
  res.send({ user: req.user });
});


app.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile", "email", "openid"],
  })
);


app.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    failureRedirect: "/login",
  }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect(`http://localhost:3001/`);
  }
);

app.get("/logout", function (req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect("http://localhost:3001/");
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect("/login");
}

//app.use("/users", users);
app.use("/drinks", drinksRouter);
app.use("/ingredients", ingredientsRouter);
app.use("/liquors", liquorRouter);
app.use("/justIngredients", justIngredients);

server.listen(3000, () => console.log("Drinks API listening on port 3000!"));
```

Comment: `User.findOne` right here.

Comment: How does User.findOne know to look into the database instance?

Comment: So internally developers of the library implemented logic to do that stuff. You can explore source code to understand in deep.